# automatically remove a div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a “noticeboard” that displays upcoming events that are occurring in the community.

Each Event is constructed as follows:

```html
<div class=”image” id=”30-9-21” data-name=”Thursday”>
    <span><img src=”cooking-class.jpg” alt=”cooking class”></span>
    <h4 id=”date”>30/9/2021</h4>
    <h4 id=”day”>Thursday Night</h4>
    <p id=”text”>Come join us for some cooking lessons.</p>
</div>
```

Once the date is less than Today’s date I would like to create a script that hides that div, so it no longer shows up on the noticeboard.

I have seen a few scripts that remove a  by clicking a button as follows:

```html
<button onclick=”remove_click()”>
    Click to remove
</button>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
    function remove_click() {
    var 30-9-21 =
    document.getElementById(“30-9-21”);
    30-9-21.remove();
}
</script>
```

I would like to automate the process so it happens automatically once the id is less than Today.

Comment: `var 30-9-21` This is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Are you using a database? Why not query for only classes where the date has not passed?

Comment: Hi Seegy, no I am not using a database, how would I construct the query?

Comment: @MiltonT how is this divs generated? how many divs will be there with id as date or name attribute as day? is there a pattern?

Comment: if you are trying to delete and recreate it with a different date why not just edit it in js

Comment: Hi Ssilas, I create the divs manually when I am informed of an event, basically I copy an existing one and alter the data etc. Yes there may be more than one event on any particular day. No pattern as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use date in `id` attribute, use special attribute for this because you may have multiple events with same date (using multiple id with same value is bad practice), so I have used `date` attribute please check below code.

And if you want to change date format from `date-month-year` to `month/date/year` update date format and date divider in `htmlDateSettings` variable in javascript below.

I have increased one day to event date, if want to hide event which are less than now please remove `filteredDate = filteredDate + msInOneDay;` in javascript below.

I have used two events with different date.

I have filtered date format because javascript need different date format than yours.

Ok now it will automatically hide events which are expired or less than one day from now.

```js
const htmlDateSettings = {
    "date-format": "d-m-y",
    "date-devider": "-"
}

removeExpiredEvents(); // call function automatically

function removeExpiredEvents() {
    let eventItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.eventItem'));
    let df = htmlDateSettings['date-format'];
    let dd = htmlDateSettings['date-devider'];
    let msInOneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    let today = new Date().getTime();

    for(let eventItem of eventItems) {
        let date = eventItem.getAttribute('date');
        if(!date) continue;

        date = date.split(dd);
        let dateFormat = df.split(dd);

        let filteredDate = `${date[dateFormat.indexOf('m')]}/${date[dateFormat.indexOf('d')]}/${date[dateFormat.indexOf('y')]}`;
        filteredDate = new Date(filteredDate).getTime();
        filteredDate = filteredDate + msInOneDay; // increased 1 day in event date
        
        if(today > filteredDate) eventItem.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="image eventItem" date="30-9-21" data-name="Thursday">
    <span><img src="cooking-class.jpg" alt="cooking class"></span>
    <h4 id="date">30/9/2021</h4>
    <h4 id="day">Thursday Night</h4>
    <p id="text">Come join us for some cooking lessons.</p>
</div>

<!-- today event -->
<div class="image eventItem" date="12-10-21" data-name="Thursday">
    <span><img src="cooking-class.jpg" alt="cooking class"></span>
    <h4 id="date">12/10/2021</h4>
    <h4 id="day">Thursday Night</h4>
    <p id="text">Come join us for some cooking lessons.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The requirement was for the process to be automated.

Comment: Ok, then why he used remove_click button?

Comment: Yes, I got it, what he told.

Comment: @Seegy Yes, Now have I update my answer.

Comment: @sparrow, I have noticed that on an ipad or iphone, the divs do not get removed, only on a pc?  Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did any error logged in console? if yes please reply what is that.

Comment: @Sparrow, I have not used console log as yet, I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: on a pc you used browser to check. right?

Comment: @sparrow Yes I did

Comment: In iphone you used safari browser. right?

Comment: @sparrow, yes safari on both iphone and ipad

Comment: replace ```let filteredDate = `${date[dateFormat.indexOf('m')]}${dd}${date[dateFormat.indexOf('d')]}${dd}${date[dateFormat.indexOf('y')]}` ``` with ```let filteredDate = `${date[dateFormat.indexOf('m')]}/${date[dateFormat.indexOf('d')]}/${date[dateFormat.indexOf('y')]}` ```

Comment: Also updated my answer. check once again.

Comment: If still not work, feel free to ask, I will find other solution.

Comment: Hi Sparrow, how would I adjust your solution so that I can add a button that will only show events for today - based on the date that you asked me to add to the div?

Comment: Remove `filteredDate = filteredDate + msInOneDay; // increased 1 day in event date` line and change `if(today > filteredDate)` to `if(today == filteredDate)`

Comment: Hi Sparrow, thank-you for all your assistance, everything is working fine.

I have started using the details/summary element so that the timetable is more user friendly on a mobile device.

Since I started wrapping the code in details/summary tags, the expired events do not get removed.

How would I alter the script you kindly supplied to get this to work.

I will send through the code that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Date.prototype.getTime() feature to compare the current time against the time that the object should be hidden.

If the object still needs to be hidden, you can simply subtract the current time from the time the div should disappear to get the milliseconds the program needs to wait.

```js
// Fetches block
let block = document.getElementById("30-9-21");

// Finds current time
let now = new Date();

// Finds time to hide object
let expire = new Date("9-31-2021");

// If the time to hide the object has already gone by, destroy the div block
if(now.getTime() >= expire.getTime()){
  block.remove();
}else{
  // Otherwise, destroy it when the time to hide the object occurs.
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    block.remove();
  }, expire.getTime() - now.getTime());
}
```

```html
<div class="image" id="30-9-21" data-name="Thursday">
    <span><img src=”cooking-class.jpg” alt=”cooking class”></span>
    <h4 id="date">30/9/2021</h4>
    <h4 id="day">Thursday Night</h4>
    <p id="text">Come join us for some cooking lessons.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So if he has 30 classes that are have passed the date, he needs to create 30 blocks? This solution will not be effective in the long run.

Comment: @Seegy the OP's original question is not effective in the long run and has plenty of room for improvement, but there is merit in this answer addressing the question of how to remove the element using JS at a point in time. Feel free to provide an answer you feel addresses the question.

Comment: Ky246, Do I just copy your code as above and add it inside a script to get this to work?

Comment: @MiltonT Yes, just add the JavaScript part of the code into a `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a database to query your data, then this is what I would suggest.

1. Place all your class information into an array of object
2. Run a for loop to loop through each class
3. Compare if the date for each class has passed today or your requirement
4. Add classes that pass your requirements to the DOM

The idea I am trying to show is that if you maintain an array of "classes", you will be able to compare the date and append it to the document only if it fulfills the requirement.

You can test it out below. Feel free to add the alt text or any other ids or classes.

```js
let classArray = [
  {
    date: '9-30-2021',
    time: 'Night',
    text: 'Come join us for some cooking lessons',
    image: 'cooking-class.jpg'
  },
  {
    date: '10-4-2021',
    time: 'Night',
    text: 'Come join us for some cooking lessons',
    image: 'cooking-class.jpg'
  },
  {
    date: '10-10-2021',
    time: 'Night',
    text: 'Come join us for some cooking lessons',
    image: 'cooking-class.jpg'
  }
];

let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

function generateClass(data) {
  let classContainer = document.createElement("div");
  classContainer.className = 'image';
  classContainer.id = data.date;
  let date = new Date(data.date);
  classContainer.setAttribute('data-name', days[date.getDay()])
  classContainer
  classContainer.innerHTML = `
    <span><img src="${data.image}"></span>
    <h4 id="date">${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}</h4>
    <h4 id="day">${days[date.getDay()]} ${data.time}</h4>
    <p id="text">${data.text}</p>
  `;
  return classContainer;
}

let today = new Date();
for(let i=0; i < classArray.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(classArray[i].date) > today) {
    document.getElementById('class-list').append(generateClass(classArray[i]));
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="class-list"></div>
```

Comment: As I understand it: Instead of using seperate divs I create an array that includes the span, the h4 the next h4 and the p and then the function generateClass will grab this data and manipulate it, and then the let today will do the calculations. I would also need to include the following which is used for filtering: class="image" id="30-9-21" and data-name="Thursday". Do I add these to the array as class:'image' id:='30/9/21' and data-name:'Thursday' ?  how do I write this inside the classContainer.innerHTML ??

Comment: I edited the answer to include this. You just need to set the class, id and add a data-name attribute. I also modified the way you display the day in the div.

Comment: Feel free to modify the code anyway you need to fit your needs. It's really more to show you that it can be automated by using a for-loop

Comment: @MiltonT this method also reduces the need to change all your class id and class names if you ever need to.

Answer (score -1):

Two things `30-9-21` cant be a variable name the interpreter wont like that so change it to `dateDiv` or something similar.

The other is that while `.remove()` will delete the element if your going to add it back later use the hidden attribute.

Also i think you can add the hidden attribute using CSS on click

```js
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    function remove_click() {
    var date =  document.getElementById(“30-9-21”);
    date.hidden = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I am a complete newbie to javaScript, could you assist me to construct this?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
      function remove_click() {
       //To just hide the div so you can call it back by making it visible
          document.getElementById("30-9-21").style.display = "none"
          clearInterval(killIfToday)
      }
      var killIfToday= setInterval({
        const currentDate = new Date(document.getElementById("30-9-21").getAttribute('id');).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
        const dateObj = new Date();
    
        
        console.log(dateObj.toLocaleDateString("en-US")); // 10/02/2021
        var formatedDate = dateObj.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
        if(formatedDate.getTime() <= currentDate.getTime()){
             remove_click()
        }
      }, 500)
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by asker ???

Comment: Thankyou Seegy, yes I need this to work automatically, not when a button is clicked.

Comment: I included Mostafa Hana's solution using the hide method and this worked, until I went back to the page and the div reappeared. Also I need this to happen automatically without clicking a button.

Comment: I also used the remove element method suggested and this also reappeared when I went back to that page.

Comment: @MiltonT I will re_edit my code and will work for you

Comment: @MiltonT I edited my code, please let me know if it works